# Question about Least Upper Bound Property in Dedekind cut construction of $R$

Tags: real-analysis

While reading Rudin's textbook *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, the book introduced the idea that a set of rational numbers does not always have the least upper bound property because you can always find a smaller upper bound for a set such as $\{p \in Q : p^2 < 2\}$.

If the members of $R$ are subsets of $Q$ satisfying the conditions for a cut, then every real number is actually a set.

For instance, if I want to think about the number $\sqrt2$, I define it as a cut $\{p \in Q : p^2<2$ or $p<0\}$.

Here's where I have a question.

If you think about it, the reason that the least upper bound property applies for the set of real numbers is because order is redefined to mean "$a$ is a proper subset of $b$" for $a,b \in R$.

What I mean by the above is, suppose there is a nonempty set of real numbers $A$. Then this set of real numbers consists of cuts.

The cut that contains all the other cuts is the least upper bound of $A$ because we defined order to mean that larger sets contain smaller ones.

So really, the least upper bound property is saying that in a set of cuts, there exists a cut $A$ such that every other cut is a proper subset of $A$?

If we consider the definition of a least upper bound that:

(1) $A$ must be an upper bound and

(2) if $B$ < $A$, then $B$ is not an upper bound.

Then (2) automatically follows from (1) because if $B \subset A$ then $A \not\subset B$ (by the trichotomy of order) and $B$ is not an upper bound.

**For a nonempty set of real numbers with its elements as cuts, does the least upper bound always exist as an element in the set?**

I've been thinking to an analogous set in the rationals $\{p \in Q: p<0\}$ where 0 is the least upper bound and not in the set, but I am not sure how I would construct a similar set of real numbers.

Comment: Are you asking if a set of real numbers always contains its least upper bound? It is false, $(0,1)$ has supremum $1$ not in the set.

Comment: Not necessarily in the given set, but in $\Bbb R$ (if the set is bounded above), and simply take the union of the cuts.

Comment: Is the union of cuts on the interval (0,1) equal to 1? How do I show this?

Answer (score 1):

**So your question is:** For a nonempty set A of real numbers with its elements as cuts, does the least upper bound always exist as an element in the set?

**The short answer is:** Yes. If A does have an upper bound, it will definitely have a least upper bound in the subset, and the least upper bound is the union of all cuts in A. The union we denote as $\gamma$.

More comments: the $\gamma$, the least upper bound of A, is also a cut in R. For proof of this, u can check appendix A of Principles of Mathematical Analysis

Hopes it will help you.